# How to call javascript function, when the user click on the frame in which the video play

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("hello");
    }
</script> 

<iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AGM0ibP1MRc" onclick="myFunction()"></iframe>
```

.Please any one. help

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this but if you want more control over the iframe for youtube you should look into the youtube iframe API. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: When i Click on the ifram so its not call the javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to overlay a transparent div and add a click event to that div. But you won't be able to click the iframe.

If you want to make the video clickable, add this

```
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
```

Working snippet :

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("Now you can play the video");
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";  //makes the iframe clickable 
}
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}
.overlay {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AGM0ibP1MRc"></iframe>
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay" onclick="myFunction()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's okay, but its need a two click for play a video. Otherwise its call a function and working is good. But whay need double click.

Comment: On the first click, you are clicking on an overlay, not on video. If you want to play the video on first click add `document.getElementById("player"). src += "?autoplay=1";` to the function. This will reload the iframe and autoplay the video. Note : Add `id="player"` on `iframe`

Comment: In this case it's just playing the first video. I add the following piece of code to play the video on which I click on the video.

Comment: Now when I clicked on any one video its play. But when I stop d the video and want to play again so it’s not working to play the video again.Untill to reload the page. So plzzz.

Comment: function submitview( id ) {
var src1 = $("#player-"+ id ).attr("src");
var result = src1.split('?')[1];
//alert( result );
if ( result == 'autoplay=1'){
document.getElementById("player-"+ id ). src;
}else {
document.getElementById("player-"+ id ). src += "?autoplay=1";
}
document.getElementById("overlay-"+ id ).style.display = "none";  //makes the iframe clickable  this is worked now perfect.